# Change size of text with different resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a background that is changing with a different resolution of browser. That is working perfectly. Then there is a text that is typed in js. I want to change the size of that text with different resolutions of browser too.

Do you know how to do that?

Normal size:
[image]

Small size:

[image]

```css
.wrap-hero-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hero-content {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 110px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 58%;
  padding: 65px;
  outline-offset: 8px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-hero-content">
  <div class="hero-content">
    <span class="typed"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, first of all is it nesseccary that your text is written in js? If you need different text on different devices work with @media querys in css. And hide them or show them in different resolutions? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries 

is it neccessary than work with javascript window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};

Comment: Read about [Responsive Font Size](https://github.com/twbs/rfs)

Comment: That text is written in js because there are three different sentences that are writting and deleting themselve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with css (you can play around with the min-width and font-sizes to suit your needs:

```
 // default for less than 800px width
    .hero-content .typed {
         font-size:10px;
    }

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .hero-content .typed {
         font-size:12px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .hero-content .typed {
         font-size:14px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 320px)
{
  .your_text
  {
    font:10px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width : 1204px)
{
  .your_text
  {
    font:16px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if my text is writting in js three different senteces. Then how could I define that?

Comment: This will change the text size of the div class where you are writing the text. Doesn't really matter if you add it from javascript or not

Answer (score 0):

create a special font size for all devices

```
$html-font-size-lg: 16px;
$html-font-size-md: 15px;
$html-font-size-sm: 14px;
$html-font-size-xs: 13px;

$paragraph-font-size-lg: 18px;
$paragraph-font-size-md: 16px;
$paragraph-font-size-sm: 14px;
$paragraph-font-size-xs: 12px;

html {

    font-size: $html-font-size-lg;
    line-height: 23px;

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        font-size: $html-font-size-md;
    }

    @media (max-width: 640px) {
        font-size: $html-font-size-sm;
    }

    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        font-size: $html-font-size-xs;
    }

}
```

or **Use em or rem for responsive font size** 
Em is a scalable unit equal to the current font size in the document. If you haven’t set font size by default, then the browser will set it for you. Browser default font size would typically be 16px. So 1em equals 16px by default. If you set font size for document 14px, 1em would equal 14px, 2em would equal 28px, 0.5em would equal 7px, etc. Recommended units are em and rem due their scalability and their mobile device friendly nature.

```
// body font size
$browser-context: 16;

// function to convert px to em
@function em($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
    @return #{$pixels/$context}em
}

html {
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: em(16);
}

h1 {
    // 72px
    font-size: em(72);
}

h2 {
    // 24px
    font-size: em(24);
}
```

THIS IS BEST PRACTICES FOR RESPONSIVE TYPOGRAPHY.